# Upgrading from Windows 7 32-bit to Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: windows-7, windows

I am upgrading from Windows 32-bit to Windows 7 64-bit.

If I choose `CUSTOM` option and install Windows on C: drive - will it wipe out all the data:

- On C: drive?

or

- On all my drives?

Comment: Unless you select to format, it won’t delete anything. Instead, you’ll end up with awkwardly mangled folder names.

Comment: Worth noting that you cannot do an in-place upgrade from a 32-bit version of Windows to a 64-bit version. I would back everything up (or, failing that, at least `ProgramData` and `Users`) and format and re-install.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it'll delete your C drive, but not the others.

Comment: Are you sure even if i choose CUSTOM option?

Comment: Yes; there is no way to migrate from x86 to x64 without a format